# Delphi 7 / Soap / Xampp. I need a good Hello World tutorial

Tags: delphi, soap

ok, I started a bounty (and may up the points). *Please* read the question. It's not so much the coding as the configuration, and I have not yet found anywhere that explains that.

---

I have read a bunch of tutorials, believe that I grok SOAP conceptually but am still having problems getting it to run.

I think that I am ok with the coding, both server and client, but my problem seems to be actually consuming the service. That is to say, which files to copy to which directories on http://localhost, what my WSDL should look like, how to run the software and what values to set in my THTTPRIO component.

Is there an extremely basic tutorial aimed at developing SOAP using Delphi and running (testing) on localhost?

Even http://www.agnisoft.com isn't helping me  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be here : 
http://www.ebob42.com/cgi-bin/Soap42.exe

Comment: Thnaks for replying (+1) Yes, Dr Bob is always a good place to look. Unrfortunately this link is for Delphi 7 Enterprise, which I don't have.  It covers coding, which I am fairly clear on but does not cover the WSDL or deploying the app on a Localhost Apache server to test it.

Comment: So may be with Marco Cantu : http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+IV+Delphi+the+Internet+and+a+.NET+Preview/Chapter+23+Web+Services+and+SOAP/